# How to uninstall the TPM simulator and use the real TPM chip on raspberry pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, iot, azure-iot-hub, windows-iot-core-10, tpm

I'm using a raspberry pi running on Window IoT Core, and connects to Azure IoT hub. When I initially wanted to provision the device I just used a TPM simulator (via the Windows Device Portal). Now I've chucked in a real TPM chip to the pi, and I want to provision the device using that chip.

But I'm not seeing an option to do that on the device portal - TPM Configuration section.
[How it looks now on the device portal now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXpDE.png)
Maybe I'm missing something obvious. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Firmware TPM (fTPM) requires special Processor/SoC support that is not currently implemented on Raspberry Pi 2 or 3. You can use MinnowBoard or DragonBoard410c  instead.MinnowBoard Max needs firmware version 0.80 or higher. DragonBoard410c provides fTPM capabilities out of the box enabled by default.

Comment: Thanks. But I've attached a dTPM : SLM 9670 iridium board. This is what I want to use on the when I provision the pi to Azure

Comment: More information please see this document(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/secure-your-device/tpm).

Comment: Hi @Michael
I was following this document [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/secure-your-device/setuptpm#setup-discrete-tpm-dtpm)

But I'm a noob on these things. To break down my approach w.r.t link I was following,
Step 1 done.
Step 2,3 skipped as I'm using an rp3.
step 4: "Based on your discrete TPM module of choice, identify its matching ACPI table here.".. I have no idea how to find a matching ACPI. So I did trial and error with every ACPITABL.dat file (Step 5).
6.Done
7.When I run t2t.exe -cap
ERROR(0x8028400f): Tbsi_GetDeviceInfo() failed.

Stuck here :(

Comment: Please refer to the topic [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/195383/configuring-a-dtpm-chip-on-raspberry-pi-running-wi.html).